# Gmap marker does not point to the current location

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I have created an application where there is a map to show the current location of the user. Here, the user permission is taken from the user, but the location is not updated, as the location to which the marker shows is somewhere in the equator.

I can't seem to understand where I have gone wrong.
Any help would be much appreciated!

````
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMap

import android.location.Geocoder
import android.location.Location
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalSoftwareKeyboardController
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places
import com.google.maps.android.compose.*
import com.shuklansh.mapsalphaproject.ui.theme.MapsAlphaProjectTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    companion object {
        const val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1234
    }

    private val locationPermissionGranted = mutableStateOf(false)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Places.initialize(applicationContext, "API KEY")
        fun getLocationPermission() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                )
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                locationPermissionGranted.value = true
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                )
            }
        }
        setContent {
            getLocationPermission()
            if (locationPermissionGranted.value) {
                MapScreen()
            }else{
                Text("Need permission")
            }
        }
    }


    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode== PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION && grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            locationPermissionGranted.value=true
        }
    }



}
@Composable
fun MapScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val fusedLocationProviderClient =
        remember { LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context) }

    var lastKnownLocation by remember {
        mutableStateOf<Location?>(null)
    }

    var deviceLatLng by remember {
        mutableStateOf(LatLng(0.0, 0.0))
    }

    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(deviceLatLng, 18f)
    }

    val locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
    locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(context as MainActivity) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
            lastKnownLocation = task.result
            if(lastKnownLocation != null)
                deviceLatLng = LatLng(lastKnownLocation!!.latitude, lastKnownLocation!!.longitude)
            cameraPositionState.position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(deviceLatLng, 18f)
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.")
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.exception)
        }
    }

    GoogleMap(
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
    ) {
        MarkerInfoWindowContent(
            state = MarkerState(
                position = deviceLatLng
            )
        ) { marker ->
            Text(marker.title ?: "You", color = Color.Red)
        }
    }
}```
````